# How to find all combinations of subarrays that add to a specific value

Tags: ruby

I need to find the first combination in a given array that adds up to a specific value. The combination needs to be the lowest indexed combination as a whole.

I have most of the problem worked out:

```
def pairs(array_ints, sum)
  array_ints.combination(2).detect {|x, y| x + y == sum}
end
```

This method doesn't give the combination with the lowest indexed pair. For example:

```
def pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10)
  array_ints.combination(2).detect {|x, y| x + y == sum}
end    

#output [5, 5]
#desired output [3, 7] because they appear earlier as a pair in the array.
```

How do I output all pairs that equal a particular sum and select the lowest indexed pair?

Comment: Are single items excluded? Are more than two items permitted? Does adjacency matter, as in your 3, 7 example?

Comment: Single items are excluded. More than two items is not permitted. They do not have to be adjacent. The index number I'm concerned about is the second numbers in the pair.  It needs to be the lowest.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your constraint from the comments: *They do not have to be adjacent. The index number I'm concerned about is the second numbers in the pair. It needs to be the lowest.*

```
def pairs(array_ints, sum)
  array_ints.combination(2).inject({}) do |acc, pair|
    first, second = pair

    #
    # Find the last occurrence of the second element. Note the use of
    # 'rindex' to search from the end of the array. The same element
    # may occur more than once ...
    #
    index = array_ints.rindex(second)

    if first + second == sum
      if !acc[:index] || acc[:index] > index
        # Store the first match, or replace it if the stored
        # index is higher than the current index
        acc[:result] = pair
        acc[:index] = index
      end
    end

    acc
  end.fetch(:result, [])
end

describe "pairs" do
  let(:array) { [10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5] }

  describe "when there are multiple combinations that add up to the sum" do
    it "finds the pair having the lowest index of the second element in the pair" do
      expect(pairs(array, 10)).to eq([3,7])
      expect(pairs(array, 8)).to eq([5,3])
    end
  end

  describe "when there is no combination matching the sum" do
    it "returns an empty array" do
      expect(pairs(array, 1)).to eq([])
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

**array_ints = [10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5, 8, 2]** and **sum = 10**

```
def pairs(array_ints, sum)
 arr = []
 array_ints.each_cons(2){|x,y| arr.push(x,y) if x+y==sum }
 print arr.first(2)
end

# output [3, 7]
```